# How to delete all files and folders in a directory besides 3 files using terminal

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi

I am trying to delete all the files and folders in a specific location on my Raspberry Pi except for `.env`, `.`, and `..`.

This seems to work:

```
find ~/my/app/here/. ! -name '.env' -type f,d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

With the exception of getting a message after saying that `rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping '/home/pi/my/app/here/.'`

How would I be able to delete everything in that folder except for my `.env` without getting the message above, or add `.` and `..` into my command?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured out the answer to my own question...

```
find ~/my/app/here/. ! -name '.env' ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -type f,d -delete
```

I was unaware that you could tag on multiple `! -name 'whatever'` to each other, but it makes sense.